# Unclaimed rewards

Tags: staking

during the staking process, validators, nominators and nomination pool members earn rewards, but they are not assigned automatically. Participants have to trigger payouts to get it. Is there a way to estimate number of unclaimed rewards for validators/nominators/pool members?  I see something for example here in the claimable column https://azero.dev/#/staking/pools
but would like to calculate it on my own based on the blockchain data

Answer (score 2):

There are different options to get the Unclaimed rewards:

- For a validator, use this `api.query.staking.erasValidatorReward`, see the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#erasvalidatorrewardu32-optionu128).
- For the pool, use this `api.query.nominationPools.rewardPools`, check the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#rewardpoolsu32-optionpalletnominationpoolsrewardpool).
- For a specific user inside the pool, use this: `api.call.nominationPoolsApi.pendingRewards` check the [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime/#pendingrewardsmember-accountid-balance).

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it based on events/calls?

Comment: The staking event Rewarded let you know when a nominator has been rewarded: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events/#rewardedaccountid32-u128-1 You can query the event and same for nomination pools: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events#nominationpools

Comment: Yes, its feasible when he's rewarded, but the question is whether I can estimate unclaimed rewards based on events until he's rewarded, before a payout